# HTML Send the form result into next page using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I was developing a website for our a power plant. I faced some problems that needs help.

The problem is, our client doesn't want to set a database on their server. That means I can only work with html, javascript and a little bit of php. There's a page for user to us radio button(choose wether the answer is "Yes" or "No"). And after using the form. We need to dynamically generate a result form(table) at the next page. I got stuck here. I can't figure it out how to send all the radio buttons value to next page(including the questions itself) here is a part of the web page
([image: screenshot])
sorry is in Chinese.(是 = YES, 否 = NO)
And a tougher situation is that I need to send image too!!!
How am I supposed to do with the image!
How to send image url from one page to another?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        
        document.getElementById('lblname').innerHTML = localStorage.checkername;
        document.getElementById('lblid').innerHTML = localStorage.checkerid;
        document.getElementById('lblteam').innerHTML = localStorage.selectedteam;
        document.getElementById('lblproject').innerHTML = localStorage.selectedproject;
        document.getElementById('lblcontractor').innerHTML = localStorage.selectedcontractor;

        
        if (localStorage.selectedteam == "儀資組") {
            console.log(a1.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
                console.log(a1[i][0]);
                $('#checkdata').append(
                    '<div data-role="collapsible" class="collapsible">' +
                    '<h3>' + a1[i][0] +
                    '</h3>' +
                    '<table class="tbinside" id="tb' + i + '">').trigger('create');
                for (var j = 1; j < a1[i].length; j++) {
                    if (j % 2 == 0) {
                        $('#tb' + i).append(
                            '<tr class="a">' + '<td class="td1">' +
                            '<input type="radio" name="yesno' + j + ' value="y">是' +
                            '</td>' + '<td class="td1">' +
                            '<input type="radio" name="yesno' + j + ' value="n">否' +
                            '</td>' + '<td class="td2">' +
                            '<b>' + a1[i][j] + '</b>' +
                            '</td>' + '</tr>'
                        ).trigger('create');
                    } else {
                        $('#tb' + i).append(
                            '<tr class="b">' + '<td class="td1">' +
                            '<input type="radio" name="yesno' + j + ' value="y">是' +
                            '</td>' + '<td class="td1">' +
                            '<input type="radio" name="yesno' + j + ' value="n">否' +
                            '</td>' + '<td class="td2">' +
                            '<b>' + a1[i][j] + '</b>' +
                            '</td>' + '</tr>'
                        ).trigger('create');
                    }
                }
                $('#tb' + i).append('<tr><td colspan="3"><h><b>備註:</b></h>' + '<input type="text" name="備註" style="width:100%;height:50px;"></td></tr>' +
                    '<br>' + '<tr><td colspan="3"><h><b>上傳照片:</b></h>' + '<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple /><output id="list"></output></td></tr>'
                ).trigger('create');
                $('#checkdata').append(
                    '</table>' +
                    '</div>').trigger('create')
            }
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
                console.log(a2[i][0]);
                $('#checkdata').append(
                    '<div data-role="collapsible" class="collapsible">' +
                    '<h3>' + a2[i][0] +
                    '</h3>' +
                    '<table class="tbinside" id="tb' + i + '">').trigger('create');
                for (var j = 1; j < a2[i].length; j++) {
                    if (j % 2 == 0) {
                        $('#tb' + i).append(
                            '<tr class="a">' + '<td class="td1">' +
                            '<input type="radio" name="yesno' + j + ' value="y">是' +
                            '</td>' + '<td class="td1">' +
                            '<input type="radio" name="yesno' + j + ' value="n">否' +
                            '</td>' + '<td class="td2">' +
                            '<b>' + a2[i][j] + '</b>' +
                            '</td>' + '</tr>'
                        ).trigger('create');
                    } else {
                        $('#tb' + i).append(
                            '<tr class="b">' + '<td class="td1">' +
                            '<input type="radio" name="yesno' + j + ' value="y">是' +
                            '</td>' + '<td class="td1">' +
                            '<input type="radio" name="yesno' + j + ' value="n">否' +
                            '</td>' + '<td class="td2">' +
                            '<b>' + a2[i][j] + '</b>' +
                            '</td>' + '</tr>'
                        ).trigger('create');
                    }
                }
                $('#tb' + i).append('<tr><td colspan="3"><h><b>備註:</b></h>' + '<input type="text" name="備註" style="width:100%;height:50px;"></td></tr>' +
                    '<br>' + '<tr><td colspan="3"><h><b>上傳照片:</b></h>' + '<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple /><output id="list"></output></td></tr>'
                ).trigger('create');
                $('#checkdata').append(
                    '</table>' +
                    '</div>').trigger('create')
            }
        }
    });
```

(upper code)We dynamically generates the radio button after we read the csv file. Thanks for your help!

p.s(If theres anything wrong. Please don't blame me, I'm new to this community)

Comment: Have you tried sending data on next page using Form methods (GET,POST).?

Comment: What do you mean by "into next page"?

Comment: @guest271314 like shopping on ebay or other online stores. After we click the "pay" button. It would dynamically generates a result form on the next web page. Which displays what you just choose.

Comment: @nana.chorage doesn't it require a server? I don't really know how to use post get. If you can provide me some sample code. It would be nice~ Thank You.

Comment: @wadestrikers When `<form>` is submitted you want to populate an `html` document with values submitted?

Comment: You don't need a database installation, there are many other ways of storing data. On the client site you could use a cookie, or even a database: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage and on the server side you can store data in files, since you have PHP, or a flat file database like SQLite: http://www.php.net/sqlite. Sending form data to the next page is a basic HTML feature. Just pick it up with the `$_POST` variable in PHP.

Comment: @guest271314 generally speaking: Yes. But details like "image", context of questions...... I need to populate all this into a form

Comment: _"I need to populate all this into a form"_ Populate a new `<form>` or render results of populated `<form>` at a different `html` document?

Comment: This one "render results of populated <form> at a different html document"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This one "render results of populated  at a different html
>   document"

You can use `FormData()`, `for..of` loop, `FileReader()`, `data URI`,  `window.open()`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="text" />
    <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
  <script>
    var form = document.forms[0];

    form.onsubmit = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var data = new FormData(this);
      var dataURL = "data:text/html,";
      var html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>";
      for (prop of data.keys()) {
        if (prop === "text") {
          var span = document.createElement("span");
          span.innerHTML = prop + ":" + data.get(prop);
          html += span.outerHTML;
        } else {
          var img = document.createElement("img");
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function(event) {
            img.src = event.target.result;
            html += img.outerHTML;
          };
          reader.onloadend = function() {
            html += "</body></html>";
            dataURL += encodeURIComponent(html);
            var doc = window.open(dataURL, "_blank", "doc");
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(data.get(prop));
        }
      }

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/JkYQAdK1hL69b2dEl1Je?p=preview

Comment: If I have multiply of things to send(radiobutton's value,images,text...).How can I modify the code above to make this happen? Thanks for answering!